# Unable to send firebase FCM message to multiple device in flutter using topics

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to register my app on a topics called weather , then trying to send push notification from postman. I have tried below code in flutter end to register or subscribe user to a topics called weather.

```
void main() async{
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('weather');
  
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then, after tried to send message using postman I'm getting message id but not getting any FCM message in my device.

[image]

subscribeToTopic is't not the way that I have tried to subscribe the device to topics ?

Comment: Have you implemented receive handlers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive?

Comment: Are you talking about notification ? if then you are messing notification attribute ! Check link https://www.postman.com/kietnguyenpostman/workspace/test/documentation/16735316-e1321694-6924-499d-83ce-ed27e719b8f4